# Design Pattern for User to choose Movie

Tags: design-patterns

I need general advice in process of designing solutions.

My general thought process is:

1. Define the required functionality in the interface and make a class to extend the interface.

Let's say a User has to login into some Cinema site, then we need

```
// id, password, address, name, age, sex etc. of the User
// login method which authenticates the login
// default Display of Movies after login
// Displaying the list as per the chosen type (select the choices of "TRENDING","MYTHOLOGY", ACTION" Movies).
```

Doubt:

So I define a class like this:

```
public class User implements IUSER {
    private String id;
    private String password;
    private Authenticate authenticate;
    private DisplayUI displayUI;
..
..
..
    User()
    {
      authenticate = new Authenticate();
      displayUI = new DisplayUI();
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    private String userName;

    @Override
    public void login() {
       authenticate.verify(userName,password);
        select("ACTION");
    }

    @Override
    public void select(String Type) {
       displayUI.display(Type);
    }
}

...
```

In this design, I am having all the required objects like Authenticate, DisplayUi etc. here. But in this way, I may have to end up with many objects in the user class(More like a Facade Pattern).

Is this the right way? Please suggest me, if could be implemented in better way.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is Object Oriented design. Application you have mentioned is a complete system. In general such systems spread over at least 3 layers namely Presentation, Business and Persistence. Sample design shown above has not passed through the design life cycle. The analysis phase seems to have been completely skipped. Typical symptoms going towards wrong design are

1. Every Class with IClass as an interface: such interfaces do not serve any purpose other than duplication of API. interface has power to change the role of any object at run time.
2. Class names sounding like 'verbs' rather than names (e.g. Authenticate). such classes will push it fast towards procedural design.
3. Entity classes (e.g. User) connected directly with presentation layer (e.g. DisplayUI)

Rather than short fix for, its required to go through an Object Oriented design process. Solid principles will also help understand it better.

Comment: @ Kedar .Thanks Kedar. Can you please suggest me book/website which gives such examples to go through an Object Oriented design process examples and which is very interactive to the developer with real stuffed examples

Comment: @Shriharsha g.r.v following books are good - 1. Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications, by Grady Booch. 2. Object-Oriented Modeling and Design with UML, by Michael R. Blaha, James R Rumbaugh. There are videos on you tube by Blaha.